# Format for a design specification for an Interactive Product

Tags: interaction-design, design, requirements

Assuming you are following a design methodology such as the IxD iterative approach which covers requirements gathering, prototyping, evaluation etc.

This creates a lot of information (data) usability and user experience goals etc, functional and non-functional requirements begin to appear. How do you collate / record all this information to produce the final design specification? Is there an industry standard pro forma?

I could create my own, however if we all did that I expect developers would get hacked off with reading specs in many different formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about creating requirements, IxD approach works well with volere requirement specification template. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Vinay, yes I had considered Volere Templates. However, if I have a large number of requirements how practical  is it to create a Volere Shell for each one ?

Comment: You could also consider creating items in Jira or trello but they won't be detailed. It's a tradeoff. The volere templates focus a lot of it a single page. I'd be happy to talk more in detail if you want.

Comment: Could you clarify why you think it's a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

this is for a student project so I am just looking for ideas on how data from all of the requirements gathering and evauations are collated, there does not seem to be a set format

Comment: In the future, use the commenting function on your question or edit the question for clarifications. Answers are for answers. Welcome to UX stackexchange ;)